# custom-server is work but when i change file directory get the error on the Nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

i created "create-next-app" and then when i m on the set this folder structure it is success, no problem, it is good work:

> +client2 
> --.next 
> --node_modules
> --public
> --...
> --server.js

But if i move the my "server.js" file to a higher partition:

> +client2
> --.next
> --node_modules
> --public
> --...
> +server.js

I get the error.

*You can try both cases using "node server.js".
*i set:
1- case this "const app = next({ dev});"
2-case this "const app = next({ dev, dir:"./client2"});"

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev, dir:"./client2" });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
  });
});
```

And here is error :

> 1 of 1 unhandled error Server Error TypeError: Cannot read properties
> of null (reading 'useContext')
>
> This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will
> be displayed in the terminal window. Call Stack useContext
> file:///Users/malibilgin/Documents/nodejs/testNodeReactTogetger/client2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react/cjs/react.development.js
> (1752:21)
> _hooksclientcontext ../node_modules/next/dist/client/components/navigation.js (130:34)
> ErrorBoundary
> ../node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js (117:48)
> renderWithHooks

Here is my githup repository
[github repository](https://github.com/muhammedalibilgin/nextjsAndNodejs)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, deleting react and react-dom from the node_modules located in the next subdir did it for me